# MySQL workbench errors when forward engineering to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have been using Mysql workbench to design my databases for a few different projects, but when i go to forward engineer to copy paste the SQL code to PHPmyadmin, or if i try a direct upload on my local setup, i'm constantly presented with errors and it is driving me nuts considering this is a program specifically for MySQL.

Not sure why I would continue to get syntax errors for code the program produced for its own language.

But often it is some variation of this same error for almost every table i try to upload.

> Static analysis:
>
> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "VISIBLE" at position
>   497) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`role_id`" at position
>   560) Unrecognized statement type. (near "REFERENCES" at position 576)
>   SQL query:
>
> -- ----------------------------------------------------- -- Table `admintom_template`.`employees` --
>   ----------------------------------------------------- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admintom_template`.`employees` ( `employees_id` INT NOT
>   NULL, `role_id` INT NULL, `hire_date` DATE NULL, `title` VARCHAR(255)
>   NULL, `dob` DATE NULL, `payrate` DECIMAL(8,2) NULL, `pay_type`
>   VARCHAR(8) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`employees_id`), INDEX
>   `fk_employees_roles1_idx` (`role_id` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_employees_roles1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES
>   `admintom_template`.`roles` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'VISIBLE,   CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_roles1`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
>       R' at line 13

Sometimes I will see a remark about the ASC function the program adds.

So i'm a bit confused why MySQL workbench seems unable to produce error free code for its own software. And i really dont know what I should be doing to correct the stated errors.  The "visible" one shows up a lot, and im not even sure why that is there.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a matter of MySQL version. Check what version you are targeting in WB preferences.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269

Comment: thanks, i think version may have been the issue.